# <button> does not work

Tags: jquery, html, button

I'm trying to create a button that hrefs to another page. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="new_user"> 
<button id="buton_user_nou">Creaza User
</button>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('#buton_user_nou').click(function(){
location.href='/register.htm'
})
```

The button is completely inactive, in all browsers. It doesn't even highlight when hovering...
Any pointers please?

Comment: Add jQuery and a document ready function !

Comment: Where is the JavaScript located in HTML document? Make sure you followed the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery. Everything you need to know to get started is explained there.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing zemi colon, also its advised put the event registration codes inside document ready. this will ensure that dom element exists while adding the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buton_user_nou").click(function() {
        location.href='/register.htm';
    });
});
```

Comment: But i still have the main issue, that the button is completely inactive, nothing happens when i click on it, it doesn't even highlight..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you placed your script, but the problem might be that the script gets executed before the DOM has finished loading, so there is no button for jQuery to find.

As adeneo pointed out, just wrap the code within a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buton_user_nou').click(function() {
    location.href='/register.htm'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try..

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#buton_user_nou").click(function() {
    location.href='/register.htm';
  });
});
```

this way it will load before the document :)